# Popen - Reading stdout and stderr without freezing or closing stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen

I'm writing a script in Python that interacts with a jar file, the jar file at some point can ask for user input through stdin, however it can also print out an error.

For this I'm using `subprocess.Popen` however I'm currently getting stuck when trying to read the output and error output, write to stdin if necessary and doing the same again.

However when using `Popen.stderr.read()` it freezes as there is no error to read, and when using `Popen.communicate()` to get the output, I can no longer send more data to the processes' STDIN.

How could I get around this issue? Here's my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen (["java","-jar","something.jar"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as process:
    # Closes STDIN, unable to communicate back
    # stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    # Hangs forever if no STDERR is ever printed
    # stdout = process.stdout.read()
    # stderr = process.stderr.read()
```

Comment: Related or maybe even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python